# webapi parameter is null

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am starting WebApi tutorial but I just faced a problem that parameter in action is a null.

Below is the tutorial code.

WebApi

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("Register")]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }
    var raw = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    var user = new ApplicationUser() { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };

    IdentityResult result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, Result.Password);

    if (!result.Succeeded)
    {
       return GetErrorResult(result);
    }

    return Ok();
    }
```

WebApi Client

```
static string Register(string email, string password)
{
    var Result = new RegisterBindingModel()
    {
        Email = email,
        Password = password,
        ConfirmPassword = password
    };
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var response = client.PostAsJsonAsync(
                "http://localhost:7399/api/Account/Register",
                 Result).Result;
        return response.StatusCode.ToString();
    }
    }
```

Register action receives http request but model is always null. So the raw variable shows like this

`{"Email":"test@gmail.com","Password":"Test@123","ConfirmPassword":"Test@123"}`

But when I tried sending http request using Postman it worked. As request body was read for model binding. The raw variable was empty. I don't know what's wrong with my client. I followed exactly tutorial code. Should I specify content-type?

Comment: Put your PostAsJsonAsync Method code here  @jays

Comment: Are you sending it from the client through HttpPost or Put? Have you tried adding the [HttpPut] on the method definition?

Comment: Find my Answer please try and let me know @jays

Comment: You need the `[HttpPost]` decorator.

Comment: can you try out answers given and let know its working or ot

Answer (score 1):

make variable name same i.e. in `Register` method change `var Result` to `var model` and have a try.

---

it should be `frombody` , i.e. get parameter value from post body

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register([FromBody]RegisterBindingModel model)
```

Comment: It's not necessary to write frombody we can do directly also

Comment: But we should know when and where to use frombody @Pranay

Comment: Thanks for your help. But frombody is not necessary. I already tried.

Comment: @jays - you tried with applying httppost ? , and can you please check that your property name you are passing as post artument is same as object property name in web api

Answer (score 0):

Add HttpPost And Use below Methods

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("Register")]
    public async Task<IHttpActionResult> Register(RegisterBindingModel model)
    {
     //your code
    }
```

**Use this Methods:-**

```
  public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> PostAsJsonAsync(this HttpClient client,
    string requestUri, object requestObject, Dictionary<string, string> requestHeaders = null,
    int? timeoutMilliSeconds = null)
    {
      var jsonContent = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(requestObject);

      var requestContent = new StringContent(jsonContent, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

      return await SendAsync(client, requestUri, HttpMethod.Post,
          requestContent, requestHeaders, timeoutMilliSeconds);
    }


    public static async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(
    this HttpClient client,
    string requestUri, HttpMethod httpMethod, HttpContent requestContent = null,
    Dictionary<string, string> requestHeaders = null, int? timeoutMilliSeconds = null)
    {
      var httpRequestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage
      {
        RequestUri = new Uri(requestUri),
        Method = httpMethod,
        Content = requestContent
      };

      if (requestHeaders != null)
      {
        foreach (var requestHeader in requestHeaders)
        {
          httpRequestMessage.Headers.Add(requestHeader.Key, requestHeader.Value);
        }
      }

      if (timeoutMilliSeconds.HasValue)
      {
        var cts = new CancellationTokenSource();
        cts.CancelAfter(new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, timeoutMilliSeconds.Value));
        return await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage, cts.Token);
      }
      else
      {
        return await client.SendAsync(httpRequestMessage);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Hi, I just wanted to use HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync and know why it didn't work. Thanks,

Comment: Can you please use my code??and let me know if its work for you??